Dialog for the datepicker is not opening
(Edit) For the one who asked me whether the type is right
https://preview.webpixels.io/purpose-website-ui-kit/docs/plugins/datepicker.html
the link above is what i am referring to.
I am using the datepicker plugin from the flatpicker.
I am using React and integrating it with plain html.
  const [displayDate, setDisplayDate] = useState(new Date()); // display date being used as the value


// function that is handling the change of the date
  const handleDateChange = (e) => {
    const thisDate = e.target.value;
    const dateObj = new Date(thisDate);
    const isoDateString = dateObj.toISOString();

    const startDateObj = new Date(dateObj);
    startDateObj.setDate(startDateObj.getDate() + 1);
    const start = startDateObj.toISOString();

    setStartDate(start);
    setSelectedDate(isoDateString);

    setDisplayDate(thisDate);
  };
 

          <!-- this is the input field for the datepicker-->
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control form-control-md"
            data-toggle="date"
            placeholder="Select date"
            value={displayDate}
            onChange={handleDateChange}
          />

Its just the simple thing that i am expecting out of this is for the datepicker dialog, where you choose a date and such to open, but in this code it does not
To clarify whether or not i have added the stylesheets and the script for the flatpicker, i have.
Date picker input field in my code
that is how it looks, the input field is visible but when clicked the date picker dialog dont open which should somewhat look like this
This is how it looks in the docs
been trying for hours now please help if you can

Didn't you forget to initialize the datepicker? As described in the manual here: https://flatpickr.js.org/getting-started/#usage It isn't obvious from the code piece that you've given. It looks like this is just a text input without any date picker behavior.

No, I have not initialized the datepicker, and i dont think so i have to. I am using the purpose theme, and using the datepicker as the plugin by flatpicker
https://preview.webpixels.io/purpose-website-ui-kit/docs/plugins/datepicker.html
this is what i am referring to. And the docs dont mention anything about initializing the flatpickr.
For clarificiation i am using the reactjs the traditional way directly embedding reactsjs into the plain html, and i am really new to this approach though this is one of the oldest way to do things. I am not sure if i can import flatpicker just like

Are you certain that the type shouldn't be date?

Yes, I am certain that the type must be text.
Please refer this
https://preview.webpixels.io/purpose-website-ui-kit/docs/plugins/datepicker.html

Could you describe what debugging you have done? In particular what the input element looks like and the varioius values encountered in the click handler [also ensuring there are no JS or other errors in the devtools console].

In order to initialize the datepicker plugin add the data-toggle="date" on any text input. Ok, you are already doing that. Now, please make sure flatpickr.min.js is loaded. See "Network" tab in your developer tools. That js file adds the actual datepicker behavior, and in your case it doesn't seem to work for some reason.
